# Custom lifetime management in DI containers (wcf proxy: Unity vs Castle Windsor)

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, unity-container

I've found nice post: [Singleton WCF Proxy](http://javiercrespoalvez.com/2008/09/singleton-wcf-proxy.html).

It is about the implementation of WCF proxy life scope using **Castle Windsor** DI container.

Implementation of the abstract class `AbstractLifestyleManager` from `Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle` namespace overrides 3 methods: `Resolve`, `Dispose` and `Release`. In the `Release` method we have access to the **context**, from which we can resolve service instance.

I've copied the code from that post (with a small change) below:

```
public class SingletonWCFProxyLifestyleManager : AbstractLifestyleManager
{
    private object instance;

    public override object Resolve(Castle.MicroKernel.CreationContext context)
    {
        lock (base.ComponentActivator)
        {
            if (this.instance == null)
            {
                this.instance = base.Resolve(context);
            }
            else
            {
                ICommunicationObject communicationObject = this.instance as ICommunicationObject;
                if (communicationObject != null &&
                    communicationObject.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        communicationObject.Abort();
                    }
                    catch { }

                    this.instance = base.Resolve(context);
                }
            }
        }
        return this.instance;
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.instance != null)
        {
            base.Release(this.instance);
        }
    }

    public override void Release(object instance)
    {

    }
}
```

I would like to provide the same functionality using **Unity** container. It looks like the `LifetimeManager` class from `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` namespace (and optionally `IRequiresRecovery` interface) is dedicated for that.

All methods that class is providing are shown below:

```
public class SingletonWCFProxyLifestyleManager : LifetimeManager, IRequiresRecovery  
{
   public override object GetValue()
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public override void RemoveValue()
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public override void SetValue(object newValue)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   #region IRequiresRecovery Members   
   public void Recover()
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }    
   #endregion
}
```

**And here is the question:**

*How to provide the same functionality in the second example (using Unity), as it was done in the first example (using Castle Windsor) ?*

(PS: There is no access to the context of the container, so how I can resolve the object ?).

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer my question (I hope that correctly..).

I've found this post [Writing Custom Lifetime Managers](http://tavaresstudios.com/Blog/post/Writing-Custom-Lifetime-Managers.aspx). I've been trying to implement solution I've described previously in details, based on that post and the previous one: [Singleton WCF Proxy](http://javiercrespoalvez.com/2008/09/singleton-wcf-proxy.html).

Below is what I have created. Of course I have to test that code. For the first look, it is rather ok, but I'll see later.

```
public class SingletonWCFProxyLifestyleManager : LifetimeManager, IRequiresRecovery, IDisposable
   {
      private static readonly object _locker = new object();
      private Guid _key;

      public SingletonWCFProxyLifestyleManager()
      {
         _key = Guid.NewGuid(); 
      }

      public override object GetValue()
      {
         Monitor.Enter(_locker);
         object result = Storage.Instance.Get(_key);
         if (result != null)
         {
            ICommunicationObject communicationObject = result
                                                       as ICommunicationObject;
            //If the proxy is in faulted state, it's aborted and a new proxy is created
            if (communicationObject != null &&
                communicationObject.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
               try
               {
                  communicationObject.Abort();
               }
               catch
               {
               }

               Dispose();
               return null;   //Return before releasing monitor
            }
            Monitor.Exit(_locker);
         }
         return result;
      }

      public override void RemoveValue()
      {

      }

      public override void SetValue(object newValue)
      {
         Storage.Instance.Set(_key, newValue);
         TryToReleaseMonitor(); 
      }

      #region IRequiresRecovery Members

      public void Recover()
      {
         TryToReleaseMonitor();
      }

      #endregion

      private void TryToReleaseMonitor()
      {
         try
         {
            Monitor.Exit(_locker);
         }
         catch(SynchronizationLockException)
         {
         } // This is ok, just means we don't hold the lock
      }

      #region IDisposable Members

      public void Dispose()
      {
         object result = Storage.Instance.Get(_key);
         if (result != null)
         {
            try
            {
               Storage.Instance.RemoveAndDispose(_key);
            }
            catch
            {
               ICommunicationObject communicationObject = result as ICommunicationObject;
               if (communicationObject != null)
               {
                  communicationObject.Abort();
               }
            }
         }
      }

      #endregion
   }
```

`Storage` utility class has been created for caching instances of services (it contains hashtable ans a few utility methods, like `Get` or `RemoveAndDispose`), but it is too simple for pasting it here.